# Angular 8 accountService is undefined in loginService

Tags: service, jhipster, angular8

As you can see we want to our application lazily load admin module.
It was working fine when we include admin module in app.module.ts, but that was not lazily loading way.
Am I right?
So remove adminmodule from app.module.ts
Here comes the question loginService has a dependency service called accountService.
When this application started, the accountService is always undefined.
I don't know how admin module affect the service.
Can somebody give me some advice? Thanks!

Below is the related code(from my understanding)
app.module.ts

```
 ...imports

 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxWebstorageModule.forRoot({ prefix: 'jh', separator: '-' }),
    NgJhipsterModule.forRoot({
      // set below to true to make alerts look like toast
      alertAsToast: false,
      alertTimeout: 5000,
      i18nEnabled: true,
      defaultI18nLang: 'en'
    }),
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    CoreModule,
    HomeModule,
    AccountModule,
    LayoutRoutingModule,
    NgIdleModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    // AdminModule,
    ApprovalModule,
    BatchJobModule,
    ShowCaseModule,
    BatchJobShowCaseModule,
    // jhipster-needle-angular-add-module JHipster will add new module here
    EntityModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [IcMainComponent, NavbarComponent, ErrorComponent, PageRibbonComponent, ActiveMenuDirective, FooterComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthExpiredInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ErrorHandlerInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: NotificationInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [IcMainComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private dpConfig: NgbDatepickerConfig) {
    this.dpConfig.minDate = { year: moment().year() - 100, month: 1, day: 1 };
  }
}
```

app.route.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { errorRoute, navbarRoute } from './layouts';
import { DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED } from 'app/app.constants';

const LAYOUT_ROUTES = [navbarRoute, ...errorRoute];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        {
          path: 'admin',
          loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
        },
        ...LAYOUT_ROUTES
      ],
      // { enableTracing: DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED }
    )
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

loginService.ts

..imports

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LoginService {
  constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private authServerProvider: AuthServerProvider) {
    console.log('loginSerive constr');
    console.log(this.accountService); *-------undefined*
  }

  login(credentials, callback?) {
    const cb = callback || function() {};

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.authServerProvider.login(credentials).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.accountService.identity(true).then(account => {
            resolve(data);
          });
          return cb();
        },
        err => {
          this.logout();
          reject(err);
          return cb(err);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  loginWithToken(jwt, rememberMe) {
    return this.authServerProvider.loginWithToken(jwt, rememberMe);
  }

  logout() {
    console.log(this.accountService);  *-------undefined*
    this.authServerProvider.logout().subscribe(() => 
          this.accountService.authenticate(null)
    );
  }
}
```

account.service.ts

```
...imports
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
export class AccountService {
  private userIdentity: any;
  private authenticated = false;
  private authenticationState = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(
    private languageService: JhiLanguageService,
    private sessionStorage: SessionStorageService,
    private _menuService: IcMenuService,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  fetch(): Observable<HttpResponse<Account>> {
    return this.http.get<Account>(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/account', { observe: 'response' });
  }

  save(account: any): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.post(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/account', account, { observe: 'response' });
  }

  authenticate(identity) {
    this.userIdentity = identity;
    this.authenticated = identity !== null;
    console.log(this.authenticated);
    this.authenticationState.next(this.userIdentity);
  }

  hasAnyAuthority(authorities: string[]): boolean {
    if (!this.authenticated || !this.userIdentity || !this.userIdentity.authorities) {
      return false;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < authorities.length; i++) {
      if (this.userIdentity.authorities.includes(authorities[i])) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  hasAuthority(authority: string): Promise<boolean> {
    if (!this.authenticated) {
      return Promise.resolve(false);
    }

    return this.identity().then(
      id => {
        return Promise.resolve(id.authorities && id.authorities.includes(authority));
      },
      () => {
        return Promise.resolve(false);
      }
    );
  }

  identity(force?: boolean): Promise<Account> {
    if (force) {
      this.userIdentity = undefined;
    }

    // check and see if we have retrieved the userIdentity data from the server.
    // if we have, reuse it by immediately resolving
    if (this.userIdentity) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.userIdentity);
    }

    // retrieve the userIdentity data from the server, update the identity object, and then resolve.
    return this.fetch()
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        const account: Account = response.body;
        if (account) {
          this.userIdentity = account;
          this.authenticated = true;
          console.log('--------------------I have been changed!!!-----------------------')
          // After retrieve the account info, the language will be changed to
          // the user's preferred language configured in the account setting
          if (this.userIdentity.langKey) {
            const langKey = this.sessionStorage.retrieve('locale') || this.userIdentity.langKey;
            this.languageService.changeLanguage(langKey);
          }
        } else {
          this.userIdentity = null;
          this.authenticated = false;
        }
        this.authenticationState.next(this.userIdentity);
        this._menuService.updateMenuByRoutes(<Routes>account.menus);
        return this.userIdentity;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.userIdentity = null;
        this.authenticated = false;
        this.authenticationState.next(this.userIdentity);
        return null;
      });
  }

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return this.authenticated;
  }

  isIdentityResolved(): boolean {
    return this.userIdentity !== undefined;
  }

  getAuthenticationState(): Observable<any> {
    return this.authenticationState.asObservable();
  }

  getImageUrl(): string {
    return this.isIdentityResolved() ? this.userIdentity.imageUrl : null;
  }

  getMenus(): any {
    return this.isIdentityResolved() ? this.userIdentity.menus : null;
  }

  getSessionTimeoutMin(): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.get(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/session-timeout-min', { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
      map((resp: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        return resp;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must tell Angular to instantiate accountService to be available (instatiated) before loginService.

Hence, you declare it as a provider into your module.

in **app.module.ts** add

```
providers: [AccountService],
```